# BoundField and Its header text are not being displayed in same column in gridview control of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="CompanyGridView" runat="server" BackColor="#2d437d" 
            BorderWidth="1px" DataKeyNames="CompanyID"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" 
             Style="margin-top: 300px; margin-left: 30px;"
            Width="1100px" ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="No record found" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
            RowStyle-BackColor="#cccccc" RowStyle-ForeColor="black" 
            AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            OnRowCommand="CompanyGridView_RowCommand" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server"  
                              CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert New Record" 
                               CssClass="button" />
                        <th colspan="6">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton Text="Details" runat="server" 
                         CommandName="Details" />
                    </ItemTemplate>   
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText=" " />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="CompanyID" 
                 ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
                ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessPhone" 
                 HeaderText="BusinessPhone" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyCode" HeaderText="CompanyCode" 
                ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
               ItemStyle-Width="150" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Hi I am having problem in Gridview control my CompanyID and its data from datasource are being displayed in different columns. I want them to have in same column. The problem is CompanyID is showing nothing while Company Name is showing data of CompanyID and so on. Basically this problem has arrived when I have used "Insert New Record" button in  but I need that button too.

Comment: refer this **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx**

Comment: otherwise post your code in online compiler like **http://dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/20/Aspnet-Gridview-basic-example-for-insert-update-and-delete-the-records.aspx**

Comment: Check your query what it's resulting from the DB? Are the value bonded to the Grid-view is correct?

Comment: yes my query is correct only the column text and value are being displayed in different rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help but my bad luck these could not help me.
What helped me was that I had to just add a  tag below my "Insert New Button"
and in different  I had to add my BoundFields. Here is my corrected code.

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="CompanyID" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BusinessPhone" HeaderText="BusinessPhone" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyCode" HeaderText="CompanyCode" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="150" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unwanted th and tr tag in the template field.Replace you template field code with below code.

```
           <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server"
                        CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert New Record"
                        CssClass="button" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Details" runat="server"
                        CommandName="Details" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Also I think you should move out the button "Insert New Record" from GridView control.

Comment: I need "Insert New Record" button above header so I have used these tags like th and tr

Comment: So put button outside the gridview control in a separate row.

Comment: No, I want that button in separate header of gridview only

Comment: you can create the same row with header style using css.

Comment: can you please give me an example of the same like how can I do that.